# Is there a way to distinguish between PCH and CPU connected PCIe slots on motherboard?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, pci-express

I have an ASUS prime z370-A  motherboard. It has the following pcie ports layout (as can be seen on this picture https://www.asus.com/media/global/gallery/LABeazMNCf93fg9W_setting_fff_1_90_end_1000.png):

- pciex1_1
- pciex16_1
- pciex1_2
- pciex1_3
- pciex16_2 (it has only x8 electrical contacts)
- pciex1_4
- pciex16_3 (it has only x8 electrical contacts)

I wanted to use two virtual machines with discrette gpu passthrough for each. I have discovered that they are in one iommu group. Then I have read [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/gwsw6y/iommu_groups_explained_or_how_to_run_dual_gpus/), which says that consumer intel cpus do not support acs for its direct pci lanes, but all pch lanes are supporting acs. Seems like pciex16_1 and pciex16_2 are connected directly to cpu.

But I also have read that If you insert the second gpu to the pciex16_2, then pciex16_1 becomes an x8 speed. This means that pcie slots can change its "length".

Now I am wondering if that pciex16_3 slot is connected to chipset or to cpu. I have found [this question](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/how-do-i-know-if-my-pcie-lanes-go-through-my-chipset-or-directly-to-my-cpu.3228609/), which says that typically on z chipsets it is pch slot. But there is no any explanation about how to destinguish them generally on other chipsets.

I am in doubt about pciex16_3 because on [intel site](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/125903/intel-z370-chipset.html) they say that Supported Processor PCI Express Port Configurations
can work as 1x16 or 2x8 or 1x8+2x4. And as I said above about pciex16_1 is able to swith to x8 mode, I thought that in case it is cpu based pcie slot, inserting second gpu to pciex16_3 could switch to that third configuration, which is pciex16_1 to x8, pciex16_2 to x4 and pciex16_3 to x4.

The problem is that I cannot check that without disassembling my pc.  There is no physical space to insert a gpu to pcex16_3, because it is double slot gpu. So I probably need a riser for that slot. But before I buy it, I want to be sure that it pch based slot.

So my question is: how do I determine if pcie slot is direct connected to cpu or via pch?